# Render data based on range selector & average when displaying larger scale data

Tags: highcharts

I have around 8000 data points which needs to be plotted using highcharts, the resolution of the chart data is 2seconds, I wanted to plot for latest 30min first(range selector is defaulted to 30m) and then based on range selector events, I would want to render the chart data using some php code, is this possible??, please guide me.

Also, when range of 1day is selected/clicked, there are too many data points and the chart is very slow to respond to label events or zoom, Can I display averaged data meaning, when 1 day is selected display data points with resolution of 1min and not 2seconds data??

Something like what this demo page describes; http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping
The data is rendered smoothly when zoomed on any particular region, I would want something like this please.

Answer (score 0):

But what is wrong with example you send? Highstock's target is to display that number of points and that's why dataGrouping was created. If you want to show only using Highcharts, see [master-detail](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail) example.